# Arabian language doesn't work in angular-gettext?

Tags: angularjs, angular-gettext

I prepared ar.po file with translations, compile it into translations.js (along with other languages), but when I try `setCurrentLanguage("ar");` it doesn't appears, I see default string constants instead. However, other languages work perfect, for example `setCurrentLanguage("fr");`

**Edit:**

I also can see "[MISSING]" near every string when `gettextCatalog.debug = true;`. Seems like angular-gettext doesn't see arabian strings, however it exists in translations.js.

Is there some workaround?